# Running java program in windows

Tags: java

I've developed a Java program in Eclipse and ready to release it.
I exported it to Java Runnable JAR file, then tried to run it from command line by 'java -jar myprog.jar'. I'm getting a message "no main manifest attribute in myprog.jar".
What should I do to create and run the executable jar file properly?
Thanks.

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute

Comment: This question is answered at least a thousand times on the web already. Please do some research before asking...

Comment: @l4mpi When you see questions that demostrate no research effort, you should down vote them.

Comment: @Raedwald I already did that, and left the comment to explain why. But the question was already at +2 when I found it, not sure why anyone would upvote it.

Comment: After fixing this problem, as described, you may use NSIS to create exe for your jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include a `Main-Class` property in the `META-INF/Manifest.mf` file like this:

```
Main-Class: full.packagename.ClassName
```

This will allow you to run the program with `java -jar myprog.jar` in any platform that supports Java, not only Windows.

You can read more about this in this Oracle Java Tutorial chapter [Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) which shows you how to set that programmatically (although you can just edit the file before packaging if you want).

In Eclipse you can set that in 'Run Configurations' (see [how to setup "Main Class" in "Run Configurations" in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397440/how-to-setup-main-class-in-run-configurations-in-eclipse))

If your project uses Maven, you can configure that with the [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html):

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <mainClass>your.packagename.ClassName</mainClass>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

If you are using Ant, you can use the `<manifest>` option from the [JAR Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html)

```
<target name="make-executable-jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="myprog.jar">
        <fileset dir="build/main/classes"/>
        <manifest>
           <attribute name="Main-Class" value="your.packagename.ClassName"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an entry point to your bundled jar application. This information is provided within the `jar:META-INF/Manifest.mf` file. The main entry description can be done by adding the `Main-Class` header as follows:

```
Main-Class: packagename.classname
```

The `packagename.classname` should have a method with signature `public static void main (String[] args)`
This will allow the `java` process to recognize your main class at runtime and execute it.

Recall that this stays a valid method within Windows box or any platform supporting java.