# Eclipse breakpoint debugging from the begin not from its position

Tags: java, eclipse, breakpoints

I have a problem in Eclipse (with Java 8) that I add a breakpoint for a function in some class in the project. But when the debugging starts, it is from the beginning of the program (from the main method!). Of course, I do not want to follow all the program so please what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you have a class or method breakpoint...

- You can press `F8` key to jump to next point or you can
- Delete the breakpoint.

---

To modify them: open debug perspective and take a look to breakpoints:

[image]

if you don't have this, please take a look to other answers. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help! 
I have just one breakpoint (for the function) when I open the breakpoints tab. Even so pressing F8 after the start of the debugging has solved the problem and I get into the function immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the "Debug/Run Configuration..." and uncheck to button to start in debugging in the main method.

[how to setup "Main Class" in "Run Configurations" in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397440/how-to-setup-main-class-in-run-configurations-in-eclipse)

Uncheck/Check "Stop in main".

[image]

Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Thank you! 
It does not work and I have just one main class. I will try to explain the problem clearly :
Let's say I have the main class and class2 which contains a function "funInClass2 " :
I want to see the execution steps of  "funInClass2 " so I add the breakpoint there.
But when I press F6 to start the debugging, it starts from the first line in main method in class1 !!
I have used visual studio before for another programming language, and what I know that usually the execution has to work independently and stops just where the breakpoint is !! and that is what I want.

Comment: Try uncheck "Stop in main".

Answer (score 0):

Select your debug configuration from menu **Run->debug configurations...**

Go to main tab and uncheck **Stop in main** checkbox.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! 
I tried this but it does not work, It still starting the execution from the main method !!