# Main class in eclipse launcher for maven archetype

Tags: eclipse, maven-archetype

How to include the java "main" class in the launcher / run configuration in maven archetype project?

run.launch:

```
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.localJavaApplication">
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_PATHS">
    <listEntry value="/${artifactId}/src/main/java/MY/PACKAGE/STRUCTURE/Start.java"/>
```

The result (after archetype generation) should look like `/MYPROJECT/src/main/java/MY/PACKAGE/STRUCTURE/Start.java`. So, the main issue is how to replace the dynamic java package structure, since it's different for each project.

Property `${package}` resolves to "**MY.PACKAGE.STRUCTURE**" rather then the required "**MY/PACKAGE/STRUCTURE**".

Comment: Looks like you want below solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397440/how-to-setup-main-class-in-run-configurations-in-eclipse

Comment: @SeanH Sorry, but my question is about the maven archetype, which will generate that launcher file. Thanks for taking a look at my issue.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  You can edit the pom.xml file directly.  If you don't mind,  I can paste some content for the plugin used to generate the one single jar file for the package.

Comment: @SeanH My issue is a maven archetype issue. I need a archetype directive, which is able to resolve the dynamically assigned java package structure in the archetype generation step, which results in the package structure with dashes instead of dots.

Comment: OK.  Understood.  You need a dynamic generation based on the java package definition in the generation step but not manually editing in the hard code pom.xml?

Comment: @SeanH Sort of... The package definition should be resolved in a property, which has "/" instead of ".". The property is referenced/replaces in a eclipse launcher configuration. The generation process itself is automatically done by maven archetype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my solution for other users, which might stumble across the same issue.

Define a new property in
`my-archetype/src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml`:

```
<requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="package-with-slash">
        <defaultValue>${package.replace(".", "/")}</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
```

Note, that the replacement is done by the [apache velocity engine](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.3/user-guide.html).

Then, reference it in the `run.launch`:

```
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.localJavaApplication">
    <listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_PATHS">
        <listEntry value="/${artifactId}/src/main/java/${package-with-slash}/Start.java"/>
```